# Rough Smart objects problem in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Adobe CC(2015) latest version and the behaviour of the smart objects isn't normal. When I paste a vector from Illustrator to Photoshop, the vector looks low quality or rough.

ORIGINAL
[image]
IN PHOTOSHOP
[image]

However, if I click over the smart object layer(in Photoshop)and this is opened in Illustrator, the vectors looks as the original one.

VECTOR OPENED IN ILLUSTRATOR FROM PHOTOSHOP SMART OBJECT
[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have the vector layer selected, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> (to activate transform controls or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> on mac) then look in the top options bar, there is a little checkbox that says Anti-Alias, check it, and it should fix your problem.

Comment: I am reading this in 2021, and this is still not the default setting, and that absolutely baffles me.