# Smart object anti aliasing Photoshop CC 2015

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, smartobject, anti-aliasing

I get the new version of photoshop CC 2015. 
Now when I past a vector from illustrator directly on photoshop they create me a smart object but they are no anti-aliasing at all.

May someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: This is a common issue, see this question for the answer http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55877/rough-smart-objects-problem-in-photoshop/55881#55881

Comment: The selected answer in @MephistonX's link doesn't mention that when you place as Smart object, it enters Free transform automatically, and you can select `anti-aliasing`in that moment. Of course if you've already placed the Smart object earlier, you have to activate Free transform to do that.

Answer (score -1):

@Thiago  It's because your photoshop document "Image size" either has a very low "Pixel dimension" setting or the "DPI" is set very low (72dpi considered low).  For example, if you have a PS document set at 150px by 150px, make sure your DPI is about 300dpi or so. This will keep everything sharp as you work. OR you can work at 72dpi but make sure you really bump up the that pixel dimension of 150px by 150px to something north of 600px. You can always export at a lower pixel dimension but this will keep everything sharp as you are working. Hope this helps.

Comment: DPI has no affect on this at all. A 150px image is still a 150px image no matter what DPI you set

Comment: Yes, I meant PPI not DPI.  Thank you for pointing that out.