# Why are my lines all jaggedy?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, smartobject

I did an illustration in Photoshop, all with Shape Layers only. All the lines are smooth and perfect within the working file. It's perfect when I export it into a png or jpg also. Problem arises when I place that exported image into another psd document. The (smooth)lines now appear jaggedy(pictured below). Note that this happens @ 100% zoom. And, the placed image is of much higher resolution than the document in which it is placed.

The original artwork was done in A3 size @ 300ppi.
The receiving document is a relatively low res 900px wide @72ppi.
I have a hunch that the problem is because of this. Can you help me find out what the problem is?

Thanks.

[image: Placed image with jaggedy lines]

Comment: Looks like you're placing it with no anti-aliasing. Does [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/55877/52050) solve it?

Comment: Hi Cai, thanks for your response. 
How do you go about turning on the anti-aliasing when placing an image? I am not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you're exporting the image into a file type that contains pixels only. The shapes will no longer be vector-like, but just hard pixels.

When you scale down these pixel images, photoshop will often created jagged lines while scaling down as your original amount of pixels do not fit in the smaller image anymore.

For me I prefer to create a [**Smart Object**](https://helpx.adobe.com/nl/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html) out of the original artwork and place it into the new, smaller document. From there I scale down. This usually gives the best quality for me as the original artwork even in that new document is still all shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried the 'smart object' way. It did not work for me. What I know is that the Resizing of the placed image in the new document IS the issue. When I place it, at its original dimension, it looks perfect, but once I resize it down, I get the jags.

I have already tried the 'reduction' resampling method too. This did not solve it for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the size of the original image before export to the exact size you want it to be in the final document, that will utilize the vector lines for the resize and might stop it from pixelating in the final document.